# Can I optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

This very simple query is taking a lot of time:

```
SELECT text, url, docid 
FROM retrieve 
LEFT JOIN citations2 
ON citations2.fromdoc = retrieve.docid 
WHERE citations2.todoc IS NULL 
LIMIT 10;
```

It has a left join with a NULL condition... could that be the cause? I have put indices everywhere.

Here is the slow-query log:

```
# Time: 130404  8:00:31
# User@Host: em[em] @ zebra [130.239.162.142]
# Query_time: 27.006579  Lock_time: 0.000019 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 90682
use em_bg04;
SET timestamp=1365055231;
SELECT text, url, docid FROM retrieve LEFT JOIN citations2 ON citations2.fromdoc =   retrieve.docid WHERE citations2.todoc IS NULL LIMIT 10;
```

Here is a schematic view of the involved tables, together with the sizes (keep scrolling down to see the output of `EXPLAIN` for the query)

[image: Table citations2]

[image: Table retrieve]

Here's the output of EXPLAIN:

[image]

So it seems that it has to go through the whole table... .I of course read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html), but I can't make sense of it. So, is there anyway of making this query faster?

Comment: Try adding the where clause in `ON` clause `SELECT text, url, docid 
FROM retrieve 
LEFT JOIN citations2 
ON citations2.todoc IS NULL AND citations2.fromdoc = retrieve.docid 
LIMIT 10;`

Comment: @Meherzad Much better now! Thanks (if you copy your comment to an answer I will accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

You are taking advantage of short circuit, so if first condition goes false it wont go for checking the second condition..

Hope it helps...

```
SELECT 
   text, 
   url, 
   docid 
FROM  
   retrieve 
LEFT JOIN 
   citations2 
ON 
   citations2.todoc IS NULL AND 
   citations2.fromdoc = retrieve.docid 
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Meherzads query looks promissing. But I would use his query in combination with a newly created index

`IDX_FROMDOC_TODOC` which contains both columns.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do you think that the optimizer would be able to use a composite index in the query as written by @Meherzad? I know I should try myself and see, but that would imply to stop a few things now :-(

Comment: I would try the index the other way around, `todoc_fromdoc`, to match the order the columns are checked in the test. Depending, however, on how many columns have NULL `todoc`, this may not help at all.